# How can I add hidden/invisible text fields or values into a document?

Tags: docusignapi

How can I add hidden text fields or values into a document?

I have to receive documents and update a database with certain values. I want to add hidden fields into a document so that I could access the values when I get the envelope. How can I do that? The hidden fields I found in the documentation were focused on hiding sensitive data from a receiver. I want the field to be completely hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [custom fields](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-labels).

Custom fields are meta-data, hidden values that are associated with an envelope and you can use API to get/set them.

They are text fields limited to 100 characters, but you can have as many of them as you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'm wondering if there is something like that but per document or even template when working with composite templates

Answer (score 0):

Meta-data can be added at the envelope, document, and/or recipient (signer) levels.

Envelope-level meta-data can be optionally shown on the certificate of completion.

Here's a [live API example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Webhook%20JSON%20notification%20format%20with%20metadata%20) that demonstrates use of the different types of meta-data while creating an envelope

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I saw the link but I couldn't find a reference to meta-data associated with the document. I saw Custom Fields but that is per envelope. I'm wondering if there is something like that but per document or even template when working with composite templates.